# Erro ao baixar imagens de um site com CURL via PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um pacote de imagens em uma pasta que funciona assim: `nome-do-produto-m.jpg`, para o tamanho médio.

Agora quero baixar o tamanho grande.

Fiz um código para ler as imagens do diretório local, trocar a letra do `m` para `g` e baixar as novas imagens. Aparentemente ele funciona, mas as imagens vem todas com tamanho `0kb`.

**Meu código:**

```
<?php
$path = "arquivos/";
$diretorio = dir($path);

echo "Lista de Arquivos do diretório '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";
while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
//echo "<a href='".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";
    $fotogrande = str_replace('-m.', '-g.', $arquivo);

    //echo $fotogrande;

    $url = "www.site.com.br" . $fotogrande;

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $fp = fopen('fotogrande/'. $fotogrande, 'wb');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);


}
$diretorio -> close();
?>
```

Exemplo de **URL válida** gerada pelo meu script: https://www.site.com.br/product/14667-sal-temperado-gostinho-alho-e-sal-200g-g.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*- mas as imagens vem todas com 0kb*"

**Não vem**! Você está criando esta imagem aqui:

```
$fp = fopen('fotogrande/'. $fotogrande, 'wb');
```

O problema é que seu `curl` não está alcançando a "imagem grande" no tal site. O que resulta em um arquivo criado e sem ser preenchido com o "suposto" conteúdo vindo do `curl`.

Para entendermos o que está errado de fato, é interessante adicionar uma verificação de erros na execução do `curl`:

```
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
```

No seu caso em específico, o erro é:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Para resolver este problema, precisa adicionar uma cadeia de certificação atualizada à sua requisição.

Uma forma simples e eficaz que foi recomendado numa [pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316732/5988245) pelo [@SchizoDuckie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18077/schizoduckie) é a seguinte:

1. Baixar a cadeia de certificados em: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem;
2. Mover/colar uma cópia para a raiz do seu script - lado-a-lado;
3. Adicionar à requisição do `curl`:

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__).'/cacert.pem');
   ```

Vale lembrar que o mais correto é definir este arquivo direto na diretiva `curl.cainfo` do `php.ini`. O que vai tirar a necessidade de adicionar um a um à todas as suas requisições com `curl` que usufruam de SSL.

Exemplo de código funcional **e reproduzível**:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://treichel-img.azureedge.net/product/14667-sal-temperado-gostinho-alho-e-sal-200g-g.jpg';

$curl = curl_init($url);

$arquivo = fopen('imagem.png', 'wb');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $arquivo);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__).'/cacert.pem');
//      http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem <<<<------------^

curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
fclose($arquivo);
```

Comment: podemos conversar por chat? Eu não entendi o que você quer dizer, pois se eu der um echo na linha, ela está montando o caminho correto

Comment: @RicardoGonçalves Chega mais no chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90925/baixando-imagens-de-um-site-com-php

Comment: funciono que é um doja :P

Comment: @RicardoGonçalves Levando o PHP ao extremo, né?! Kkkkk